# Java JNI interface to implement an object destructor

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

So my question is basically if there is even the possibility to implement a custom made JNI so that it can give the possibility to remove immediately the object from the heap instead of waiting for the Garbage Collector to act over it.

My question goal is focusing mostly on the memory that consumption when using temporary functions that create a lot of objects to calculate somthing.

for example: I have a function like this:

```
public Integer[] countDuplicates(int[] values) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> l = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Integer c;
    for (int v : values) {
        c = l.get(v);
        if (c == null) {
            c = 0;
        }
        l.put(v, c + 1);
    }
    Integer[] result = l.values().toArray(new int[l.size()]);
    // < A Way to free the Map from the heap>
    return result;
}
```

as you can see, there is no need for the Map after the end of the method, so, my question is, is there any way, either using JNI, or Implementing any command on the GC, or even a tagword that will force the removal from the heap after the method run?

Comment: You can't do this. The compiler doesn't emit any code for an object reference going out of scope, and the JVM can only tell that an object has become unreachable via GC.

Comment: There is no much sense in doing this. Garbage collectors are created to be aware that almost all objects are short lived.

Comment: “remove … the object from the heap” is an entirely wrong mindset. Yes, the term “garbage collector” invites into that wrong thinking, but it’s simply not how a computer’s memory works. The data of an object will stay in its location even when its memory is already part of the free memory, until it gets overwritten by other data. What you call “remove the object” actually means “add its memory to a list of free memory”, but that would require a JVM that maintains such a list of (small) free memory chunks, which no modern JVM does. Without such a list, you can’t add an object’s memory to it.

Comment: The deal here, ishaving a mix of both concepts, where having a GC will help prevent having memory leaks, and managing resources when they are clearly not needed and their scope is too short, will help the stop-the-world GC.

Comment: @Holger of course it's not a wrong mindset when you want to manage as most of the resources you have when it comes to critical processes. And yes, java is still being used on small components that need to have quick and real time responses, and having a bunch load of memory sometimes it's not something to even be considered

Comment: Just take the time to read a comment and understand, before responding. You are arguing with what you want. But I explained, *how it works*. Objects are not removed. There is no free list that you could add an object to. You asked whether there is such a function and the answer is no, there’s not only no such function, it’s impossible to add such a function, given the way the memory management actually works.

Comment: Answering regarding one's mindset is different from answering objectively to the question. I'm not going to argue about such matter as it is not the purpose of such forum. About the latter, nothing is _impossible_, rather just a matter of time and complexity, hence why I referred to JNI (or any other similar deep changes in JVM), and my only concern is if the language itself will allow such changes, being it a matter of changing the way JVM works, or will it corrupt the entire workflow of the language

Comment: afaik, there is no such thing. but it will be impossible to provide one too, because if this is allowed (somehow) - you are directly interfering with GC, that means eviction, GC barriers, etc etc. There is no way for the JVM to allow such functionality, ever. But of course your mind set is somehow wrong, you can't "remove" garbage. What actually happens is that _live_ objects are moved, everything else is marked as "free", this is how _any_ GC algorithm on the JVM works. And of course you might worry for something that might not _ever_ hurt you, prematurely.

Comment: You might consider pooling objects instead? Pooling is considered bad but it will at least alleviate you of the problem of trying to reclaim the heap space right away.

Comment: Of course, “nothing is impossible”; it’s all a matter of time and complexity, so if you don’t fear a complexity in the order of magnitude of implementing your own JVM, just go ahead. And wrong mindsets are an objective thing. A question of how to add a “roof first” mode to existing house building procedures would bear a wrong mindset. Starting with the roof might be possible, but not with the established building procedures. It’s fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: @Eugene, thanks, that was kinda what I was looking for, the next possible way of dealing with Garbage on the run, instead of letting it fill up to 80/90% over and over when sometimes I already know they are not going to be needed, and using weak references sometimes will induce more overhead on structure and such than the benefict it will yield out

Comment: And of course I know that I'm going against the concept of GC languages, but that was my last attempt before switching to a language where I could control the memory allocation by hand. The syntax and clean code of java is great, but the performance itself is just atrocious...

Comment: @Jakes instead of saying that the performance is terrible, I would suggest having proof for that and asking questions. It heavily depends on the version of the jvm, GC algorithm, etc. If you honestly think that a different language that manages memory on its own is panacea, you will shortly be in a surprise, imho.

Comment: Since some very high performance applications (like stock exchange matching engines) are actually written in Java, it would seem that the language is not actually the problem.